# Keycloak and Google OAuth 2.0 redirect URI mismatch

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, keycloak, redirect-uri-mismatch, identity-provider

i have site https://fm.xxxxx.com
domain was register

and i use some load-balancer as nginx with redirect configuration for keycloak

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name fm.xxxxx.com;
        return 301 https://fm.xxxxx.com;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name fm.xxxxx.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate/xxxxx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/xxxxx.key;

 location /realms/fm-users/ {
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_pass http://fm-keycloak:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

    client_max_body_size 30m;
 }

 location /resources/ {
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_pass http://fm-keycloak:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

    client_max_body_size 30m;
 }...
```

when i try to setup google identity provider in keycloak
i created google provider, and use Redirect URI in google configuration

[image]

but google doesnt like URI

[image]

i cant change redirect uri in keycloak identity provider
and it is invalid for google

i tried use domain instead ip

[image]

but it send error when i try login use google

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch ofcourse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIyTW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON85d.png)

my site use https, keycloak not

how can i change redirect URI in identity provider in keycloak?

or what can i do?

i tried add redirectUri parameter to keycloak import.json file
and add redirectUri parameter to identity_provider_config table in keycloak DB
it doesnt help

when i used 127.0.0.1 and run all locally its works
but i need it for prod and use domain in keycloak or ip in google

maybe i need to create some redirect using nginx.conf?

Comment: Where is the full error message it should tell you what redirect uri you need to set.   https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ?si=977UR0srgX8awbD4

Comment: i am stupid,
it helped, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to copy the redirect uri from the error to the url google credential.

The port was redundant.

Comment: Please be cautious with external links; it's apparent that "Linda Lawton - DaImTo" is affiliated with the source of that YouTube link. It would be good for them (and you) to disclose that fact, so that it's not seen as overt self-promotion. Thanks!

Comment: Affiliate is normally related to applications people are selling.  it never occurred to me someone would be afraid of a YouTube link which has my name on it and in it that visually shows how to fix the common error.  I suppose I could have searched my answer history for a duplicate.   [What constitutes an affiliation disclosure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360418/244647)